# React js does not recognize me map method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-props

English is not my native language, but I will try to make myself understand my best.

In the axios_cards component I am doing a get by axios to an api json and I assign to another component the list of objects as property

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import CardsGrid from "../Pages/CardsGrid"

class Axios_cards extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props)
        this.state = {
            courses : []
        }      
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://my-json-server.typicode.com/jee4nc/myjsonserver/lista')
        .then(response => this.setState({
                courses: response.data
            }))
    }
    render() {
        const {courses} = this.state
        return <CardsGrid courses={courses}/>
    }
}

export default Axios_cards;
```

But in the component to which I assign the properties, it does not recognize the array and does not allow me to map the list

```
import React from 'react';
import Cards from "../Molecules/Cards"

const CardsGrid = ({courses}) => (
    <div className="ed-grid m-grid-3">
            {
            courses.map( e => 
                <Cards 
                id={e.id} 
                title={e.title} 
                description={e.description}
                image={e.image}
                price={e.price}
                key={e.id}  
                />)
            }
        </div>
)

export default CardsGrid;
```

**does not recognize courses to be able to map**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
CardsGrid
src/Components/Pages/CardsGrid.jsx:5
  2 | import Cards from "../Molecules/Cards"
  3 | 
  4 | const CardsGrid = ({courses}) => (
> 5 |     <div className="ed-grid m-grid-3">
  6 |             {
  7 |             courses.map( e => 
  8 |                 <Cards
```

Answer (score 3):

What if your response.data is null or not an array?

This should resolve it

```
<div className="ed-grid m-grid-3">
            {
            Array.isArray(courses)? courses.map( e => 
                <Cards  
                id={e.id} 
                title={e.title} 
                description={e.description}
                image={e.image}
                price={e.price}
                key={e.id}  
                />) : null
            }
        </div>
```

Comment: add the code you told me, and although it fixes the error, it no longer shows the cards. Could it be that the error is because the get with axios is not returning the array?

Comment: @Jee4nc exactly, once it will be an array it will show the cards, handle the response.data to be an array.

Comment: In the axios_cards component, using componentdidmount I make the request by getting to the json server and assign the value to props, but it still does not receive it as an array. From what you can see in the axios_Cards code, is there an error? Since I believe that with the validation you gave me, the error is there. 
Thanks in advance